# Tag duplicate element for SEO

Tags: jquery, html, css, seo, clone

I am creating a sticky header. I've found the easiest way to pull this off is to clone my header using jQuery and modify its style appropriately in CSS. Is there any way to mark this cloned header as having duplicate content, so search crawlers can ignore it?

I know this isn't ideal, but I was having issues with just using the original header. In particular, it would "blink" in and out when other elements on the page animate (CSS translate), and I can't figure out why. The duplicate doesn't have this problem. For usability purposes, I was thinking of putting a skip link in the duplicate for screen reader users.

****EDIT****
I solved the CSS issue. It had to do with my header having "overflow-y: hidden". I'm not sure why, but this caused the sticky header (a child element of the header with position: fixed ) to "blink" in and out while other elements were translating through the CSS transform property. Removing the overflow rule worked, and fortunately for me I didn't need it, anyway, as an inner element also had it. Hopefully someone else can read this now and have their similar issue solved.

Comment: i believe , generated elements via CSS or javascript would not be seen by crawlers unless they also fire CSS and JavaScript to retrieve infos from web document looking at the DOM

Comment: While this shouldn't be an issue with SEO, are you sure there's no better way to achieve what you need than to duplicate the content? There may be an alternative if you post details of what you have

Comment: I agree, I think you should fix the underlying css problem rather than use a hack

Comment: I'll try to post a fiddle if I can

Comment: I figured out the CSS issue. See my original question.